# Extracting thumbnail/preview image from DNG file using ExifTool throws warning and produces zero-byte JPG

Tags: exiftool

I've got a DNG file (a photo captured by Insta360 X3: single-lens mode) and I'm trying to extract the thumbnail/preview image of it so that I'll be able to upload it to my cloud drive alongside with the DNG itself for quick preview while navigating. Here's the command that I put into my Terminal (I'm on macOS Sonoma 14.2.1 and ExifTool 12.70):

```bash
exiftool -b -thumbnailimage IMG_20240108_102844_10_012.dng > thumbnail.jpg
```

but it threw and produced a 0-byte `thumbnail.jpg`:

```
Warning: Invalid EXIF text encoding for UserComment - IMG_20240108_102844_10_012.dng
```

I also tried to extract the preview image but it gave me the same result:

```bash
exiftool -b -previewimage IMG_20240108_102844_10_012.dng > preview.jpg
```

What did I do wrong / what did I miss?

The DNG file here:
https://icedrive.net/s/D5gkZ1yBWafYQRYNvPR7w3Q4Daaa

Answer (score 0):

That file doesn't appear to have any preview images, or at least none that exiftool can find.

You can see a list of all previews and thumbnails with this command

```
exiftool -G1 -a -s -Preview:all /path/to/files/
```

And [this exiftool example](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#exiftool--a--b--W-d-f_-t--c.-s--preview:all-dir) shows how to extract and save all possible previews in a file.

Exiftool's [`-v3` (`-verbose3`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#v-NUM--verbose) can provide a break-down of how the data is organized in a file.  Using that option, there doesn't appear to be any unknown data except for the `MakerNoteUnknownText` which, at only 224 bytes, is too small to hold an image.

If you are sure that the file is supposed to have a preview image, you can take the file over to the [exiftool forums](https://exiftool.org/forum/) and the author of exiftool might take a look if he has time.

Comment: Thanks! Right, I believe I've also tried that `-preview:all` flag but it still produced nothing. Strange thing is, Mac's Finder and the cloud drive I use above (IceDrive) is able to render the thumbnail/preview. Do you think it is qualified to be taken over the ExifTool Forum then? If so, into which thread I should post the file?

Comment: Finder and cloud drive might simply be reading the whole file to create a thumbnail.  Windows will do this and save the result in a file called `Thumbs.db` in each folder. Reading some posts seems to indicate that Mac caches thumbnails somewhere, but not in the `.DS_Store` hidden file.  You might try downloading a big image file and then opening the folder on the desktop. See how long that takes and then close/reopen the folder and compare the times.  [WikiMedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Large_images) has a large file category which would be a good place to check.

Comment: It does no harm to go ahead and post on the Exiftool forums.  It would best be posted in either "Newbies" or "The "exiftool" Application".  The author would probably be able to check in a day or two, unless it's a good day for bird watching :D

Comment: Alright, thanks so much! Just found some spare time to make the post (https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=15744) -- definitely I got many beautiful birds to watch over the last month XD